# Xcode 4 project template adds extra folder

Tags: xcode4, project-template

When I make a new project with xc4 I don't want it to create a folder with the same name as the project. I want the source files associated with a project template to get copied into several other folders that sit next to the project.

In the TemplateInfo.plist, I can specify which files to copy through the Definitions and Nodes arrays. In the Definitions, if I make the name ../Example.cpp then it will copy the file into the directory with the project rather than into the folder that has the project's name, which is what I want. But, if i delete that empty folder then xcode can no longer find any files because all files had to be specified relative to the auto-created folder.

Does anyone know how to get around this? Is there some way to specify which folder project files should be relative to? Or perhaps some other way to specify relative paths for files in a project template?